# How to use xquery to perform four arithmetic operations on xml nodes

Tags: xquery

```
<Expression>
            <description/>
            <minus>
                <plus>
                    <int value="2"/>
                    <int value="3"/>
                    <times>
                        <int value="5"/>
                        <minus>
                            <int value="6"/>
                            <int value="3"/>
                        </minus>
                    </times>
                </plus>
                <int value="4"/>
            </minus>
        </Expression>
```

I want to get expression like this and output the result：（2+3+（6-3）*5）-4=16

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for higher-order functions:

```
declare variable $evaluators := map {
   'int' : function($e){xs:integer($e/@value)},
   'plus' : function($e){sum($e/*/local:eval(.)},
   'minus' : function($e){local:eval($e/*[1] - local:eval($e/*[2])},
   'times' : function($e){local:eval($e/*[1] * local:eval($e/*[2])},
   ...
}
declare function local:eval($e as element(*)) {
   $evaluators(name($e))($e)
}
local:eval(Expression/(* except description))
```

The details depend a bit on aspects of the specification that you haven't shared with us, for example whether `description` can appear anywhere, whether `times` (like `plus`) can take more than two operands, etc.

Acknowledgements: I saw this problem solved in 1972 using Algol 68 by my late friend and colleague Andrew Birrell (https://cacm.acm.org/news/210689-in-memoriam-andrew-birrell-1951-2016/fulltext) and it was this problem and solution that convinced me of the value of treating functions as first-class objects.

Comment: Note, Martin Honnen's solution outputs the expression `（2+3+（6-3）*5）-4` as well as the result `16`. I was assuming you just wanted the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT 4 example as runnable by SaxonCS from Saxonica:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="4.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="operator-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'minus' : ' - ',
                  'plus' : ' + ',
                  'times' : ' * ' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="Expression">
    <xsl:variable name="expression">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="result" as="xs:decimal">
      <xsl:evaluate xpath="$expression"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$expression, $result" separator=" = "/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="minus | plus | times">
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates separator="{$operator-map(local-name())}"/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="int[@value]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or as XSLT 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="operator-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'minus' : ' - ',
                  'plus' : ' + ',
                  'times' : ' * ' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="Expression">
    <xsl:variable name="expression">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="result" as="xs:decimal">
      <xsl:evaluate xpath="$expression"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$expression, $result" separator=" = "/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="minus | plus | times">
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1"> {$operator-map(local-name(..))} </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="int[@value]">
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1"> {$operator-map(local-name(..))} </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Solely evaluation in XQuery (3) perhaps as

```
declare function local:evaluate($expression)
{
  local:evaluate-operator($expression/(* except description))
};

declare function local:evaluate-operator($operator)
{
  typeswitch ($operator)
    case element(minus)
      return fold-left(tail($operator/*), local:evaluate-operator(head($operator/*)), function($a, $op) { $a - local:evaluate-operator($op) })
    case element(plus)
      return sum($operator/*!local:evaluate-operator(.))
    case element(times)
      return fold-left($operator/*, 1, function($a, $op) { $a * local:evaluate-operator($op) })
    case element(int)
      return xs:integer($operator/@value)
    default return ()
};

local:evaluate(Expression)
```